# How to extract only time items from a hash?

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash like below:

```
{"19th Apr, 2013" => :a, "20th Apr, 2013" => :b,"Tomorrow" => :c,"5:00 PM" => :d,"09:25 PM" => :e}
```

I want the output:

as `{"5:00 PM" => :d,"09:25 PM" => :e}`

Could anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why are you using such a strange hash

Comment: @Cyle good question. I needed it to make some output while I am using `nokogiri` on the page [`tensports`](http://www.tensports.com/schedule.php)

Comment: did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
t = {"19th Apr, 2013" => :a, "20th Apr, 2013" => :b,"Tomorrow" => :c,"5:00 PM" => :d,"09:25 PM" => :e}

t.select { |k,v| Time.strptime(k,"%H:%M %P") rescue false }

#=>  {"5:00 PM"=>:d, "09:25 PM"=>:e}
```

Comment: I appreciate the use of Time.strptime

Comment: that's actually bad - because this way you are only expecting one specific time format

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"19th Apr, 2013" => :a, "20th Apr, 2013" => :b,"Tomorrow" => :c,"5:00 PM" => :d,"09:25 PM" => :e}

hash.select { |k, v| k.match /\d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M/ }
```

Gives you:

`{"5:00 PM"=>:d, "09:25 PM"=>:e}`

As far as 'perfect' regex goes, check the regex war in the other answers comments ;)

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment? I would appreciate some feedback if this answer is wrong :)

Comment: I upvoted you, just to counter balance the downvote. I also appreciate feedback on downvotes.

Answer (score -2):

More general approach:

```
 hash = {"19th Apr, 2013" => :a, "20th Apr, 2013" => :b,"Tomorrow" => :c,"5:00 PM" => :d,"09:25 PM" => :e , "23:23" => :f}

 hash.delete_if{|k,v| k !~ /\d{1,2}:\d\d/}
  => {"5:00 PM"=>:d, "09:25 PM"=>:e, "23:23" => :f}
```

NOTE:

- this also allows 24-hour format times
- this also handles the case when the hour is just one single digit

if you don't want to handle 24-hour format, then use:

```
 hash = {"19th Apr, 2013" => :a, "20th Apr, 2013" => :b,"Tomorrow" => :c,"5:00 PM" => :d,"09:25 PM" => :e , "23:23" => :f}

 hash.delete_if{|k,v| k !~ /\d{1,2}:\d\d/ [AaPp][Mm]} # am AM pm PM
  => {"5:00 PM"=>:d, "09:25 PM"=>:e}
```

Comment: `/\d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M/` might be a better regular expression ;)

Comment: True, just leave off the `[AP]M` then.

Comment: well, that's what I have as a regexp ;-)

Comment: Nope, you have `/\d{1,2}:\d\d/`. It can be more succinctly expressed the way I wrote it. :P (Regular expression war!)

Comment: Right, and TIMTOWDI says both are cool, but the latter is more succinct and should be taught to people learning regular expressions because if I ever see something like `/\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w/` in code I take maintenance over, I may have the desire to murder the person who wrote it in the first place.

Comment: I agree, someone who writes /\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w/ should be fired :-)  \d\d is shorter than \d{2} though ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28335/discussion-between-sigmavirus24-and-tilo)